# The Hindenburg's max alt was a function of its gas cell volume. Is there an equation to determine how much volume a gas fills at different altitudes?

Tags: gas, volume

I'm trying to determine the maximum altitude that an airship can safely reach.

According to this paper the answer can be determined in a straightforward manner.

[Development of an Aerodynamic Model and Control Law Design for a High Altitude Airship](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.729.126&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

The maximum altitude an airship can safely reach is a function of the size of its hydrogen or helium cells.

For example the [Hindenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ_129_Hindenburg)'s hydrogen cells could hold up to 200,000 cubic meters of gas.  As altitude increased the hydrogen would expand until all 200,000 cubic meters were full.  When the cells reached full capacity the Hindenburg was at its maximum safe altitude.  Beyond that hydrogen had to be released or the bags would rupture.

So is there a basic equation to solve something like this?

Note: I'm not sure if these are the most convenient units to use.

**Example question:**

**Altitude**: 5,000 meters

**Air Pressure**: .86 kg / centimeters squared (not sure why that's not cubed) or 83% of air pressure at sea level.

**Temperature**: 5 degrees celsius.

Given those constants how much volume in meters cubed would 17,296 kg of Hydrogen fill?

Is there an equation I can use to test different temperatures and pressures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe let's try to get some concepts right with a simple example and then turn to engineering (:

The best first guess would be to treat the gas as an ideal gas, so that $$PV=nRT$$ holds ($P$ is pressure, $V$ is volume, $n$ is # of gas moles, $T$ is temperature and $R$ the perfect gas constant). Because inside the cells $n$ is constant (until you release it, but let us ignore that at the moment), assuming the temperature is also constant if you don't move too far up, we get, at a given outside pressure (set by the outside atmosphere) that the gas would like to occupy a volume $V$ given by:

$$V = {nRT\over P}$$

and we also know that at $V_M=$2000000 cubic meters we reach the pressure $P_M$ at which the cells break. This means that if the pressure (outside) is below this number, the gas would try to expand even more than its maximum volume and will end up breaking the cells. As you mentioned, a way out is to release some gas (i.e. decrease $n$) so that the gas will tolerate even lower pressures.
To convince you of that, put $V=$2000000m3 in the formula $PV=nRT$ with different values of $n$ and you will find different breaking pressures.

So, summing up, we have a relation connecting $P$ and $V$ (at fixed $n$ and $T$ to make it easire, but in principle we can also change those values!). And we know (if you put in the numbers) the lowest pressure the system can tolerate at given $n$ and $T$ by imposing that the max volume is $V_M$.

We now need to connect this with altitude. What changes as we go higher is that the temperature drops and the pressure too. You can use the [barometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula) to connect $P$ and altitude $h$. It is basically a formula (actually, a set of formulas) that connects the pressure to a given altitude. Let us call it this connection $P(h)$. We now get:
$$P(h)V=nRT(h)$$
where in principle both $P$ and $T$ depends on the altitude. The precise details depend on how high you are and what model you decide to use. Just choose your best guess for $P(h)$ and $T(h)$ and you will find an equation connecting everything.

As a first guess, one can use constant $T=300K$ (room temperature) and $P(h)=P_0 e^{(-h/h_0)}$, where $P_0$ is $1atm$ and $h_0$ a constant you can find on wikipedia, so you get

$$P_0e^{-h/h_0}V=nRT$$ which leads to a maximum height $h_M$ (which is when $V=V_M$) of

$$h_M=-h_0 ln(nRT/P_0 V_M)$$

(only valid very close to the sea level!)